# Memory allocation. 2D array (Void function)

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, 2d, void

I followed few examples on this forum, but it seems like my program still keeps crashing at some point.

All i want to do is just use a `void function` for memory allocation.

```
void alloc(int ***matrix, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < n; i++)
    {
        (*matrix)[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }

    i = 0;
    for( ; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for( ; j < n; j++)
        {
            (*matrix)[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    int n;
    int **matrix_pp;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    alloc(&matrix_pp, n);

    free(matrix_pp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no 2D array! And being a 3-star programmer is not a compliment. As your function is `void` anyway,you should just return the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to use `(*matrix)[i]` before it's been allocated. Add:

```
 (*matrix) = malloc(n * sizeof(**matrix));
```

before your `for` loop.

Note two things here:

1) Don't cast the result of `malloc`,

2) use `sizeof(*pointer)` instead of explicitly writing out the type; this way, if you decide to change the type later, it will still work.

Further, you will need to `free` all of the allocations you have in a loop as a loop as well; otherwise, you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's all perfect now